# Replacing one and more spaces, with exactly ONE new line.

Tags: c

I'm exercise code. The thing is, to replace space from input, with a new line.

I wrote something like this:

```
int input;

while((input = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (input == ' ')
    {
        input = '\n';

    }

    putchar(input);

}
```

But I don't know how to make it change more than one space into exactly one new line. I had an idea to make something like buffer variable (ex. int buffer) and store space in there, and then check if after input, previous character was space, but I don't have any idea how to make it work :P

Comment: What? You have your code, why you are not happy with it? You want all of them gone or what?

Comment: Add a flag indicating that it was already replaced once. Really, simple logic.

Comment: @gsamaras The OP wants `s/\s+/$/`

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, I want all of them gone :P Problem with my code happens when i make more than one space, and I want my words or characters (nevermind, just input) to be one under another :P

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe simple, maybe not. Started not so long ago, still have to learn ;P

Comment: Try a state machine with three states: read a space; read something other than a space; read EOF. ...

Comment: Look at the edited answer I posted below (the one with 7 lines of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int input, last_was_space = 0;    
while((input = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if(input == ' ')
    {
        last_was_space = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(last_was_space)
        {
            last_was_space = 0;
            putchar('\n');
        }

        putchar(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaciejMakulec What is it that you don't understand? I'd gladly explain it to you

Comment: I can't get along with this if else logic :P

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of the if statement:

```
if(input == ' ') {
    while (input == ' ')
    {
        input = getchar();
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Stop deleting and reposting your answers!  If you want to fix your code, edit it in place, or test it before posting.  You can test your code here: http://ideone.com/

Comment: Still not right: input `"one   two"` produces `"onet\nwo"`.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will work for you, though the newline won't show up until the input ends or the first non-space character is entered.

```
int input = 0;
int previous = 0;

while((input = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (input != ' ')
    {
        if (previous == ' ')
        {
            putchar('\n');
        }
        putchar(input);
    }

    previous = input;
}

if (input == ' ')
{
    putchar('\n');
}
```